# How do disable all notifications on macOS and iOS?

Tags: macos, ios, notifications

I have to use a Mac at work and there's random notifications in the top right, e.g. update software, try Safari, error messages, etc.

I just want to turn them all off. I already disabled notifications for every software in the "Notifications & Focus" settings that are disableable, but e.g. "Managed Software Center" isn't disableable.
On Windows, when there's a notification, it lights up a small icon in the corner that you can just ignore.

Also, on iOS, I already disabled notifications for every app, but whenever my battery gets low, Apple engineers felt the need to pause whatever I'm doing and fill my whole screen with a popup telling me about battery levels. On Android, it just changes my battery icon to red.

How can I disable all notifications?

Comment: "Managed Software Center" isn't Apple software.  That sounds like an MDM your work machine has installed.  So you'd need to ask your local IT department if notifications from it can be disabled.

Comment: Have you tried Focus? For iOS: https://support.apple.com/HT212608 macOS: https://support.apple.com/guide/mac-help/mchl613dc43f/mac